# What does 'COB' mean in programming?

Tags: thrift, acronym

Is it 'Callback OBject'?

I keep bumping into this acronym when learning Apache Thrift.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add a reference where you found it in Thrift? Thanks!

Comment: It means Close of Business to me ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuation OBject: see line 280 of [this source file](https://apache.googlesource.com/thrift/+/master/compiler/cpp/src/generate/t_cpp_generator.cc)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is **Continuation Object**, see [this mailing list discussion](http://grokbase.com/t/thrift/dev/12c43fy2qy/how-should-i-implement-multi-threaded-clients-and-multi-threaded-connections-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

It means continuity of business. You normally say COB testing servers etc . So if something goes down on main server or due some natural calamity ,you tend to use COB server to keep the business going .